# What do you do on client side for WebGl Aquarium?

Tags: google-chrome, webgl

I am trying to work out how content is synchronized across multiple screens as shown by http://webglsamples.googlecode.com/hg/aquarium/README.html. (video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64TcBiqmVko)

All I want to know is what code gets runs on the client side? From what I can tell is there is some websocket client side code that determines what is shown.

Can anyone point me to where this is?

TIA
JD.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must make sure that all initial data is identical on all machines. Then you set up different cameras on different machines (so you can put together "meta" screen). And run your simulation, but with synchronization for every frame (or every n-th frame).

Of if your simulation is non-deterministic then you have to synchronize simulation results needed for rendering every frame.